# pandas iteration for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
def calculate(x, formula):
    return eval(formula)

col = {
    's1':{'l':100, 'w':200}, 
    's2':{'l':200, 'w':400}, 
    's3':{'l':300, 'w':500}
    }

coldf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(col, orient='index')

print(coldf)

formulacol = [{'key':'a', 'formula':"x['l']*x['w']"},{'key':'p', 'formula':"x['l']+x['w']+x['l']+x['w']"}]

for i in formulacol:
    coldf[i['key']] = coldf.apply(lambda x : calculate(x, i['formula']), axis=1)

print(coldf)
```

i have a for loop to iterate the formula list and apply on dataframe. is there anyway to avoid the for loop.

i want to call a function on each rows as i need to perform a complex thing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *formulacol*, define a dictionary with column names as keys
and respective expressions as values:

```
dct = {'a': coldf.l * coldf.w, 'p': coldf.l + coldf.w + coldf.l + coldf.w}
```

Then call *assign* with dictionary unpacking and save the result back under
the original DataFrame:

```
coldf = coldf.assign(**dct)
```

The result is:

```
      l    w       a     p
s1  100  200   20000   600
s2  200  400   80000  1200
s3  300  500  150000  1600
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand correctly your question but maybe something like this is what you are looking for?

```py
import pandas as pd

col = {
    's1':{'l':100, 'w':200}, 
    's2':{'l':200, 'w':400}, 
    's3':{'l':300, 'w':500}
    }

coldf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(col, orient='index')

print(coldf)

formulacol = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a' : coldf['l'] * coldf['w'], 
        'p' : coldf['l'] + coldf['w'] + coldf['l'] + coldf['w']
    }
)

coldf = pd.concat([coldf, formulacol], axis=1)

print(coldf)
```